# C#: Regular expression to replace all <font> tags in HTML by <span>

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to replace all <font> tags in a HTML file by <span style="..."> and retain the attributes such as font color and font size.

Here are the test cases:

```html
<font color='#000000'>Case 1</font><br />
<font size=6>Case 2</font><br />
<font color="red" size="12">Case 3</font>
```

Here is the expected result:

```html
<span style="color:#000000">Case 1</span><br />
<span style="font-size:6rem">Case 2</span><br />
<span style="color:red; font-size:12rem">Case 3</span>
```

With the C# code below, case 1 and 2 can be replaced successfully as they have only 1 style attribute. However, the second attribute in case 3 is missed. Is that possible to improve the C# code below for keeping both "color" and "size"?

```
        string pattern = "<font (color|size)=(?:\"|'|)([a-z0-9#\\-]+)(?:\"|'|).*?>(.*?)<\\/font>";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

        output = regex.Replace(output, delegate (Match m) {
            string attr  = m.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); 
            string value = m.Groups[2].Value.Trim();
            string text  = m.Groups[3].Value.Trim();

            if (attr.Equals("size")) {
                attr = "font-size";
                value += "px";
            }

            return string.Format("<span style=\"{0}:{1};\">{2}</span>", attr, value, text);
        });
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Using regex to parse/alter HTML = _EVIL_ ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Don't use regex. HTML has so many ways to write tags that you'll end with a monstrous regex. My advise is to use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) which allows you to parse and manipulate HTML. This lib is a golden nuget when dealings with HTML manipulation. And it's free and open source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Try Html Agility Pack instead.

Comment: You've got a great answer there. Maybe this could be the new canonical answer for "how do I parse HTML with Regex in C#"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As commented by @Steve B 
>   Don't use regex. HTML has so many ways to write tags that you'll end with a monstrous regex. My advise is to use HtmlAgilityPack which allows you to parse and manipulate HTML. This lib is a golden nuget when dealings with HTML manipulation. And it's free and open source.

Here you can do this by using **HtmlAgilityPack**

```
public string ReplaceFontBySpan()
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

    string htmlContent = @"<font color='#000000'>Case 1</font><br />
<font size=6>Case 2</font><br />
<font color='red' size='12'>Case 3</font>";

    doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

    foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font"))
    {
        var attributes = node.Attributes;

        foreach (var item in attributes)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals("size"))
            {
                item.Name = "font-size";
                item.Value = item.Value + "rem";
            }
        }

        var attributeValueList = node.Attributes.Select(x => x.Name + ":" + x.Value).ToList();

        string attributeName = "style";
        string attributeValue = string.Join(";", attributeValueList);


        HtmlNode span = doc.CreateElement("span");
        span.Attributes.Add(attributeName, attributeValue);
        span.InnerHtml = node.InnerHtml;

        node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(span, node);
    }

    return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Nice answer - sometimes the best answer to "how do I do this" is "don't do that, do something else"

Comment: @Ben, Thanks, - yes sometime its best :)